# Why are my component bindings undefined in its controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I'm writing a simple angular component. I'm passing a parameter as a binding and display its value on the screen. All works fine: I can see the parameter being displayed on the screen.

Component:

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);
app.component("test", {
  bindings: {
    "contactId": "<"
  },
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: () => {
    //output: 'contact id from controller: undefined'
    console.log(`contact id from controller: ${this.contactId}`);
  },
  template: "<div>Contact id from view: {{model.contactId}}</div>"
});
```

Html:

```
<test contact-id="8"></test>
```

However, when I try to access the binding from within the controller (see the console.log), the binding value is `undefined`. I don't understand how it can be available in the view, but not in the controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0GUoNqLRyygeRlqItSMV?p=preview) illustrating the problem.

Comment: I am missing something simple.  Why is "contactId"  definited in quotation marks?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When using angular's components, there is a point where the controller hasn't been wired up via the internal *linking*.  If you're trying to do this in the constructor of your controller, you haven't been *linked* to the bindings. The Component API exposes a few life-cycle hooks that you can define that will fire at certain times.  You're looking for the `$onInit` hook.

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

per docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: I think you are right, `$onInit` should be used. This works for me:
`
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.$onInit = function() {
    console.log('loaded on init');
    console.log('vm', vm.YOUR_BINDING);
    console.log('def yes?', angular.isDefined(vm.YOUR_BINDINGj));
  };
`

Comment: In some scenarios your bindings can be updated later and its values are not ready when the hook `$onInit` is call. In such cases you should use `$onChanges` and skip the first changes. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/auxcoder/4hq5gaq0/

Comment: @aUXcoder That was my issue. I tried to create the component before the data to bind to component was ready. Putting an `ng-if` directive to ensure I had the data before the component was initialized (eg `<custom-component ng-if="!$ctrl.data" data="$ctrl.data"></custom-component>`) fixed the issue.

Comment: "... after all the controllers on an element have been constructed", does this mean that one component can have multiple controllers with a single use of component tag? Is there an example?

Comment: @Buksy I think they mean that for a given HTML element, that may or may not correspond to a component, there can be more than one directive on it.  For instance `<custom-component ng-model="" nx-save=""></>`.  In this case, you have a single element, with a component controller, an ngModelController and some other directive that could have a controller.

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you use **hyphens** for bindings in HTML and camelCase for bindings in Javascript.

```
app.component("test", {
  bindings: {
    "myContactId": "<"
  }
}

<test my-contact-id="8"></test>
```

That's what I always forget to do.

Comment: For reference, and a few special cases where this could bite at you: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization

Answer (score 7):

The keyword **this** doesn't seem to works with arrow function, this works with

```
controller: function() {
   alert('contact id from controller: ' + this.contactId);
}
```

When using arrow function, **this**, seems to refer to the window object because

> An arrow function does not create it's own this context, rather it
>   captures the this value of the enclosing context

Answer (score 7):

The value for `contactId` is available on the `$scope` in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);
app.component("test", {
  bindings: {
    "contactId": "<"
  },
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: ($scope) => {
    var model = $scope.model;
    alert(`contact id from controller: ${model.contactId}`);
  },
  template: "<div>Contact id from view: {{model.contactId}}</div>"
});
```

Link to another version of your Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/y3z3gb3AHA9bhcrPNHSw?p=preview).

Comment: why can't we use this keyword when we use the arrow function style ?

Comment: You can use `this` with the arrow function style, but I think in this situation, `this.contactId` is not available yet, for reasons that @jusopi mentioned. If you had API methods, such as someController.prototype.someMethod, `this` should have what you expect. As @jusopi mentioned, the execution order won't populate `this` in the constructor (non-prototype) as expected.

Comment: I tried with a timeout and it doesn't work. As I said above, An arrow function does not create it's own this context, rather it captures the this value of the enclosing context. So with arrow function this refers to the window object, not the controller.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of that - thanks! In this situation, regardless of function syntax, `$scope` injection will solve the problem the the OP asked.

Comment: User 1058612 - thanks for the example, learned a lot.  However, tried it exactly (hopefully) as you laid it out - not working for me.  Any chance that 1.7.9 is the problem - there were changes to this version, but I'm new to this.  Any help will do - thank you

Answer (score 6):

i will suggest some changes which you would really need to avoid these unusual bugs.

```
app.component("test", {
  bindings: {
    "myContactId": "<"
  },
  controller:function(){
   var self=this;
   this.$onInit=function(){
    // do all your initializations here.
    // create a local scope object for this component only. always update that scope with bindings. and use that in views also.

       self.myScopeObject=self.myContactId
   }
  },
   template:'<p>{{$ctrl.myScopeObject}}</p>'
 }

<test my-contact-id="8"></test>
```

some points :

1. passing bindings to a component in html is always going to be kebab cased ex my-contact-id and its respective javascript variable will be cammal cased : myContactId.
2. if you are passing the value insted of the object use '@' in bindings.
   if you are using an object and passing the object to bindigs use '<.
   if you want 2-way-binding to that object use '=' in the bindings config

> ```
>  bindings:{
>       value:'@',
>       object:'<', // also known as one-way
>       twoWay:'='
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Its maybe its not the best practice, but you have a easyer access to those values:

```
$scope.$ctrl.contactId
```

You can get all the bindings in the property $ctrl inside the $scope.

I hope its help

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the code causing the "undefined" error.

1. As stated above the $onInit lifecycle hook should first be reached, the onInit is fired when all bindings have been made.

From the official documentation:[AngularJs Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an
>   element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and
>   before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this
>   element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your
>   controller.

2. The second problem you will likely have, is that your controller will not reach the lifecyclehook when using "() =>" arrow notation as a parameter for the controller function.

The problem being is that arrow notation won't have it's own scope, but rather use it's enclosing scope.
Meaning that when using "this" will refer to the window object rather than the component.
So calling this.$onInit() will be called on the window, and will not be fired, because it doesn't exist on the window.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Directives, where Components are assumed, if bindings{} is specified it appears adding those same parameters to scope{} works:

```
/*bindings: {
    modalInstance: '<',
    resolve: '<'
},*/
scope: {
    modalInstance: '<',
    resolve: '<'
},
```

*Discovered after I wrote the above that an additional scope parameter, foo, wasn't available on $scope until I assigned it from $scope.resolve. So I had to do this in $scope.init(): $scope.foo = $scope.resolve.foo. Not sure why. Guessing it has to do with my UI Bootstrap Modal + Directives usage

This may be obvious for others but wasn't for me being relatively new to AnguluarJS.

My problem was using Directives with UI-Bootstrap Modals which are compatible with Directives but designed and documented for use with Components.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add another answer as a follow up to @jusopi and the accepted answer, just for those who may encounter my issue. In regards to the component, even after the `$onInit` hook, my data was still null, as the value from the server was still not received. To counteract this (though there may be a better way to handle this situation), I also leveraged the `$onChanges` hook. `$onChanges` will return the data that has changed when it is passed it, and you can parse that information, or simply call the binding as `this.contactId` and it will be updated.

More details are provided in the [documentation](http://%20https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component